# How to change Weather on Windows 8 to Celsius?

Tags: windows-8, weather

I searched for all the webpages for how to change from Feranheit to Celsius in Weather on Windows 8.  Both methods don't work:

1) Either using Settings -> Options and change to Celsius: No such option exist.  There is only a "Disable Search".

2) Or touch any where in Weather's empty background and the Fahrenheit / Celsius option should show.  It doesn't.

So how possibly can be it be changed?  It just totally doesn't make sense.  (The machine I am using is Lenovo Yoga 13, but it should have a standard Windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

On the notebook running Windows 8, it is to "Right Click" on empty space in Weather, and some panel will show to change to Celsius.  Touching any empty space won't work.

Comment: Right side on the bottom panel